# Как убрать папку из адреса сайта?

Tags: .htaccess

Есть ссылка:

```
dite.ru/page/article.html
```

Как убрать из линка `/page/`
Что-бы стало:

```
site.ru/article.html
```

Важно что-бы страница открывалась по `site.ru/article.html`, но 
сам контент оставался лежать по адресу `dite.ru/page/article.html`

Не знаю смог-ли объяснить. Короче на сайте все страницы лежат в папке `/page/` но я не хочу отображать ее в ссылках на страницы.

Comment: используйте mod_rewrite

Comment: Что написать в htaccess?

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали? или вы ищите готовое решение?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article.html$ page/article.html [L]
```